# Выводит текст "Введенные данные не совпадают!" хотя все совпадает

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой при входе в профиль. С регистрацией и др функциями все нормально но при входе выводится текст "Введенные данные не совпадают!" хотя все данные верны.

Вот весь код login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require("db.php");

if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
    $login = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["login"])));
    $password = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["password"])));

    if(empty($login))
    {
        unset($login);
    }
    if(empty($password))
    {
        unset($password);
    }
    if($login == "" or $password == "")
    {
        exit ("Пожалуйста заполните все поля!");
    }
    else
    {
        $connecting = mysqli_query
        (" 
            SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE login='$login' 
        ");
        $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($connecting);

        if(empty($myrow['password']))
        {
            exit ("Введенные данные не совпадают!");
        }
        else
        {
            if($myrow['password'] == $password)
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = $myrow['login'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $myrow['password'];
                echo "Поздравляем! Вы успешно вошли на сайт!";
            }
            else 
            {
                exit ("Введенные вами логин и пароль не сошлись!");
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

HTML код тоже должен был тут находиться (между PHP кодом), но я убрал его.

Comment: Очень много лишнего в коде. Советую всегда верить серверам и машинам, они не обманывают. Попробуй дампнуть `$myrow['password']` и `$password` перед этой проверкой и, думаю, поймешь, в чем дело.

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в запросе. он у вас возвращает пустой результат.

Comment: Действительно, похоже запрос возвращает пустой результат. Проверил вывод запрошенной информации таким образом (вывелся текст что ничего нету):                                                                                               echo $myrow["login"];
                echo $myrow["password"];
                if(!$myrow["login"] && !$myrow["password"])
                {    echo "Тут ничего нету!";   }

Comment: Главный вопрос - почему? Весь код просмотрел но ответа не нашел.

Comment: Научитесь проверять на ошибки http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php каждый раз когда делаете запрос. Очень пригодится в жизни.

Comment: Ошибка не нашлась, вопрос актуален.

Comment: Поповщины насмотрелись? Одной строчкой решается, без ваших 100 `empty`.

Comment: кодировки смотрел?

Comment: Допишите `or die` и проверьте запрос в sql, заработает ли он там.

Comment: Виталий, попробовал, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Сергей, кодировка при подключении utf8.

Comment: Проблема актуальна 2 день.

Comment: And, проблема скорее всего не в этом (да и я только начинаю изучать PHP).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден! Все оказалось очень просто - у меня 2 name="login" у кнопки и у текстфиелда. Простите, тупанул.